# MD5 support for mongocxx (mongodb c++ driver) with GridFS

Tags: c++, mongodb, driver, mongo-cxx-driver

Uploading a file to GridFS storage with the `c++` driver doesn't create a **md5** entry in the files collection. IE:

```
auto uploadStream = bucket.open_upload_stream( filename );
uploadStream.write( buffer, size );
uploadStream.close();
```

[image]

Using the `node.js` api (and probably others) instead does it by default, (and you can optionally disable it).

Is it a missing feature or is it hidden somewhere I could not see? There's no mention of it in any of the docs:

> Current mongocxx documentation 3.4.0, latest at the time of writing [mongocxx 3.4.0](http://mongocxx.org/api/mongocxx-3.4.0/classmongocxx_1_1database.html#ab5fedc0193a470bd51f44072160edcbc)

PS: I know this specific file is smaller than the 16Mb recommended size for GridFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explained in [GridFS specification](https://github.com/mongodb/specifications/blob/master/source/gridfs/gridfs-spec.rst#generic-find-on-files-collection), `md5` checksum is **deprecated**.

In particular:

> **Why are MD5 checksums now deprecated? What should users do instead?**
>
> MD5 is prohibited by FIPS 140-2. Operating systems and libraries
>   operating in FIPS mode do not provide the MD5 algorithm. To avoid a
>   broken GridFS feature on such systems, the use of MD5 with GridFS is
>   deprecated, should not be added to new implementations, and should be
>   removed from existing implementations according to the deprecation
>   policy of individual drivers. Applications that desire a file digest
>   should implement it outside of GridFS and store it with other file
>   metadata.